# Stripe ACH + Plaid : 'account_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string'

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I am passing the account ID retrieved from the connected Stripe account as follows (slightly altered to preserve privacy):

```
plaidClient.createStripeToken(accessToken, 'acct_3C2QhSG4bc0yBRVY', function(err, res) {
```

Which returns this response:
'account_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Account ID that function is expecting is not your Stripe Account ID, it's the account ID returned from Plaid link. The onSuccess callback for the Plaid link handler will be resolved with two arguments, the first is `public_token` and the second is `metadata`. The account ID expected here is available on that `metadata.account_id` property.

```
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
      console.log('Customer-selected account ID -> : ' + metadata.account_id);
  },
  // ...
```

Comment: Perfect, I got it working with your response. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: happy to help! :D